# How to extract varname from raster?

Tags: r, raster, netcdf

I read a NetCDF file as raster.

```r
library(raster)
r <- brick("./DATA/consecutive_wet_days_index_50_.nc",
varname="consecutive_wet_days_index_per_time_period")
```

Now, how to extract the specified `varname` from the raster `r`? I need the varname later to name the plots. Also, how to extract varname if not species while reading?
[image]

A sample NetCDF file is here:

https://mega.nz/file/HE8X3SbB#06DxcP2_jJkTItyealz9UACKrkQ31_4_Xmkx_r-fB28

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of those maybe?

```
gsub("(.*)\\\\","", r@file@name, perl=TRUE)
# [1] "consecutive_wet_days_index_50_.nc"

r@file@datanotation
# [1] "FLT4S"
```

You may examine the structure using `str(r)`.

Or use `capture.output` hack.

```
x <- capture.output(r)
trimws(gsub("(.*)\\:","", x[9], perl=TRUE))
# [1] "consecutive_wet_days_index_per_time_period"
```

Comment: Not the filename, I am looking for variable name, since the file contains multiple variables. I could not find it in `str(r)`

Comment: @ajilesh I see, I came up with a hack, see edit.